# Blank space at bottom of page

Tags: css, html

[In this site](http://www.indiosnativosvalvulados.com.br/gustavo_chupador_de_piroca) I'm having an issue, there is some big blank space at the bottom of the page, the space disappear if you open the chrome dev tools or if you edit ANY property whith dev tools opened.
Already tried to remove the clearfix from the footer, set the `overflow: hidden;` and set both body and html to `height: 100%;` and `min-height: 100%;`, and remove the slider to see if is any JS problem when calculating the html height. Now, I have no idea of what are happening,

Thanks!

Comment: openning the element inspector makes it disappear but after closing the inspector, it still disappears, can you try letting the `html` style as normal (without `display:block`)? What's the purpose of that style? so weird to me.

Comment: There is an JS error on plugins-ck.js "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", Not relevant, but would worth to check if this causing the issue.

Comment: Thank yout guys, @KingKing the that property was just one of my tries to solve the problem. But that is solved right now.

The facebook like-box as causing the issue, I just set `overflow: hidden;` to everything inside the fb-like-box class ant bum! White space is gone, the iframe was causing this.
And @user3107931 I'll check it later, but looks like some issue in the flexslider plugin.
Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.container:after, header:after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Change "\0020" to " ";

```
.container:after, header:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Already tried man, thanks.
Tha problem was the Like Box iframe.